# how do i make a if statement for AM/PM like < 12 am >=12 pm

Tags: vb.net

i want to make am/pm if statement in vb.net and i dont know how to do it

```
 If txtHourEnter.Text < "12" Then
            lblTimeIn.Text = txtHourEnter.Text + ":" + txtMinEnter.Text + "AM"
        ElseIf txtHourEnter.Text >= "12" Then
            lblTimeIn.Text = txtHourEnter.Text + ":" + txtMinEnter.Text + "PM"
        End If
```

i tried this but whenever i type 2 it says pm and if i type 1 it say am

Comment: You should parse your date using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-7.0 and check against that struct instead of strings.

Comment: You really ought to be using `DateTimePicker` controls. They will display the date in the appropriate format and they will prevent the user entering invalid values. You can then just get the time as a `TimeSpan` from `myDateTimePicker.Value.TimeOfDay`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to work directly with the `Text` property from controls like that. It just makes calculations hard. Always convert the text to a data type you can compute with, then do the computation, and then finally convert back to something you can display.

Try this:

```
Dim entered As String = txtHourEnter.Text + ":" + txtMinEnter.Text

Dim time As DateTime
Dim display As String = "Invalid entry"
If DateTime.TryParse(entered, time) Then
    display = time.ToString("h:mm tt")
End If

lblTimeIn.Text = display
```